# Code doesn't work unless I use variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphics

My question is pretty simple, I don't know if I'm overlooking something or what.
But why does this work:

```
def main():
    win = GraphWin("My Circles",500,500)
    x = random.randint(50,450)
    y = random.randint(50,450)
    cir1 = Circle(Point(x,y),8)
```

But this doesn't:

```
cir1 = circle[((Point(random.randint(50,450)),random.randint(50,450)),8)]
```

Comment: You are missing an uppercase C on circle, not sure if this is the problem or just a typo. You also have one to many brackets after the first random integer.

Comment: Your ``Point`` only gets the first random number as input, so you are doing ``Circle((Point(x), y), 8)``. Also the [ and ] look wrong.

Comment: cir1 = Circle(Point(random.randint(50,450),random.randint(50,450)),8)
did u try this?

Comment: Are you sure you have `circle[ ... ]` in your code? It should probably raise an exception since I don't see how a circle could be indexed....

Answer (score 2):

You have a bunch of syntax errors. If you fix the capitalization and the parentheses it will work as you intended.

```
cir1 = Circle(Point(random.randint(50,450),random.randint(50,450)), 8)
```

Comment: Works thanks! Overlooked it after staring at the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like just an error with your parentheses. The only parameter that is actually sent to the Point method is your first random int, not the second one.

```
// this closes off the Point constructor before you pass in the second point
cir1 = >>c<< ircle >>[<< >>(<< (Point(random.randint(50,450)   >>)<<    ,random.randint(50,450)),8) >>]<<
// should look like this:
cir1 = Circle(Point(random.randint(50,450), random.randint(50,450)),8)
```